# How can I balance http request in https for every website in Haproxy?

Tags: haproxy, openssl

For example, in this config file, just first HTTP connect request is balanced by Haproxy.
Is self-signed certificate work with this case? I don't know how to generate one self-signed certificate for every website for Haproxy.

```
defaults
    timeout connect 5000s
    timeout client 5000s
    timeout server 5000s
listen main-proxy
    bind 127.0.0.1:8080
    mode http
    balance leastconn
    server proxy1 127.0.0.1:8081 no-check
    server proxy2 127.0.0.1:8082 no-check
```

HTTPS vs HTTP balance example:

```
#HTTTP(multiple balance, this is what I want to things)
$ nc -l 127.0.0.1 -p 514 -u |grep -F 'www.haproxy.org'
<14>Mar  6 18:56:44 haproxy[4684]: 127.0.0.1:47754 [06/Mar/2019:18:56:43.170] main-proxy main-proxy/proxy1 0/0/0/360/844 200 37955 - - ---- 3/3/2/1/0 0/0 "GET http://www.haproxy.org/ HTTP/1.1"
<14>Mar  6 18:56:44 haproxy[4684]: 127.0.0.1:47758 [06/Mar/2019:18:56:43.629] main-proxy main-proxy/proxy2 0/0/0/548/548 200 488 - - ---- 2/2/1/1/0 0/0 "GET http://www.haproxy.org/size.js HTTP/1.1"
<14>Mar  6 18:56:44 haproxy[4684]: 127.0.0.1:47766 [06/Mar/2019:18:56:44.195] main-proxy main-proxy/proxy2 0/0/1/557/558 200 215 - - ---- 4/4/2/1/0 0/0 "GET http://www.haproxy.org/size.css?1436x801 HTTP/1.1"
<14>Mar  6 18:56:46 haproxy[4684]: 127.0.0.1:47776 [06/Mar/2019:18:56:45.547] main-proxy main-proxy/proxy1 0/0/0/575/593 200 1830 - - ---- 13/13/11/7/0 0/0 "GET http://www.haproxy.org/img/btn_donate_SM_eur.gif HTTP/1.1"
<14>Mar  6 18:56:46 haproxy[4684]: 127.0.0.1:47758 [06/Mar/2019:18:56:45.542] main-proxy main-proxy/proxy1 0/0/0/377/605 200 15400 - - ---- 12/12/10/6/0 0/0 "GET http://www.haproxy.org/img/HAProxyCommunityEdition_60px.png HTTP/1.1"
<14>Mar  6 18:56:46 haproxy[4684]: 127.0.0.1:47792 [06/Mar/2019:18:56:45.558] main-proxy main-proxy/proxy1 0/0/0/593/594 200 495 - - ---- 11/11/9/4/0 0/0 "GET http://www.haproxy.org/img/fr-off.png HTTP/1.1"
<14>Mar  6 18:56:46 haproxy[4684]: 127.0.0.1:47800 [06/Mar/2019:18:56:45.585] main-proxy main-proxy/proxy1 0/0/0/566/566 200 949 - - ---- 11/11/8/3/0 0/0 "GET http://www.haproxy.org/img/ipv6nok.gif HTTP/1.1"
<14>Mar  6 18:56:46 haproxy[4684]: 127.0.0.1:47784 [06/Mar/2019:18:56:45.553] main-proxy main-proxy/proxy1 0/0/0/600/600 200 3319 - - ---- 9/9/7/1/0 0/0 "GET http://www.haproxy.org/img/haproxy-pmode.png HTTP/1.1"
<14>Mar  6 18:56:46 haproxy[4684]: 127.0.0.1:47780 [06/Mar/2019:18:56:45.550] main-proxy main-proxy/proxy2 0/0/0/551/829 200 19247 - - ---- 7/7/5/5/0 0/0 "GET http://www.haproxy.org/img/World_IPv6_launch_banner_256.png HTTP/1.1"
<14>Mar  6 18:56:46 haproxy[4684]: 127.0.0.1:47812 [06/Mar/2019:18:56:45.711] main-proxy main-proxy/proxy2 0/0/0/668/668 200 376 - - ---- 7/7/4/4/0 0/0 "GET http://www.haproxy.org/img/ipv6back.png HTTP/1.1"
<14>Mar  6 18:56:46 haproxy[4684]: 127.0.0.1:47788 [06/Mar/2019:18:56:45.555] main-proxy main-proxy/proxy2 0/0/0/824/824 200 441 - - ---- 7/7/3/3/0 0/0 "GET http://www.haproxy.org/img/en-off.png HTTP/1.1"
<14>Mar  6 18:56:46 haproxy[4684]: 127.0.0.1:47804 [06/Mar/2019:18:56:45.698] main-proxy main-proxy/proxy2 0/0/0/681/681 200 2261 - - ---- 7/7/2/2/0 0/0 "GET http://www.haproxy.org/img/pwby.gif HTTP/1.1"
<14>Mar  6 18:56:47 haproxy[4684]: 127.0.0.1:47766 [06/Mar/2019:18:56:45.546] main-proxy main-proxy/proxy2 0/0/0/1572/1572 200 1729 - - ---- 8/8/2/1/0 0/0 "GET http://www.haproxy.org/img/btn_donate_SM_usd.gif HTTP/1.1"

#HTTPS(just one balance, this is not what I want):
$ nc -l 127.0.0.1 -p 514 -u |grep -F 'www.haproxy.org'
<14>Mar  6 18:54:33 haproxy[4630]: 127.0.0.1:47380 [06/Mar/2019:18:51:44.606] main-proxy main-proxy/proxy1 0/0/0/1088/169260 200 84273 - - ---- 2/2/1/0/0 0/0 "CONNECT www.haproxy.org:443 HTTP/1.1"
```

Comment: How do you test your load balancing? From a single client or from multiple ones? Do the client actually close their connections neatly between attempts, or do they keep the connection alive and reuse it for their next attempt?

Comment: @MikaelH `How do I  test my load balancing`, I view the log and find Haproxy just say "CONNECT example.com:443 HTTP/1.1" for https website, not per HTTP request as browser see(lot small files HTTP request). such behavior lot reduce balancing among single HTTPS session.

Comment: Well of course you don't want to create additional TLS connections for every query a client makes. Each additional connection requires its own TLS handshake with the remote server, making them comparatively expensive, both in terms of latency for your client and in terms of computation for the servers involved. How it works is your client establishes a "TLS tunnel" with the server, and then it sends individual requests within this tunnel, ending up with exactly what you see: One client making a single long connection to the server until it's done or until the connection times out.

Comment: Suggested reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security